# Commons Digester add Singleton Object

Tags: java, apache-commons-digester

I Have a XML and I am using commons-digester1.8 to create a object of my bean.
My bean contains a reference to another Bean which is singleton.
Is there any way I can create/get the reference of singleton object and get my bean populated.

My xml contains `<language/>` tag and for this tag bean has `Language.class` reference.
`Language.class` is singleton and to get the instance of `Language.class`, I have to call `getInstance(String name)` of language class.
But When I try

```
        d.addObjectCreate("rights/language",Language.class);
        d.addCallMethod("rights/language", "getInstance",1);
        d.addCallParam("rights/language",0);
```

It gives an error. Is there a way to achieve this.
Thanks,
Gagan

Answer (score 0):

Usually with the singleton design pattern/(design flaw) there's a static method on the class for getting the instance of the singleton:

```
Language language = Language.getInstance();
language.doSomething();
```

You seem to be messing round with reflection, is there more to this than you're letting on.